# php array unique type check

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `array_unique` to get rid of the duplicate values in an array. But, the problem is `array_unique` does not consider data types while checking for duplicates. For example:

```
$a = [1, true, null, false];
$u = array_unique($a);
var_dump($u);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>int(1)
  [2] =>NULL
}
```

But, if you consider data types every value of the array are unique. I know I can fix this by running a loop. But, is there a better way or an alternative to `array_unique` by which I can achieve this?

Comment: you will have to custom loop

Comment: From the documentation: *Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`*. It's intended for strings and numbers, not arbitrary types.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution that seems to work:

```
<?php
function array_really_unique($array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $item){
        foreach ($array as $key2 => $item2)
            if ($key2 != $key && $item2 === $item)
                unset($array[$key]);
    }
    return $array;
}

$a = [1, true, null, false, false, false, true, null, 2, 3, "hi", 2];
$u = array_really_unique($a);
var_dump($u);
?>
```

> **Result:**
>
> array(7) { [0]=> int(1) [5]=> bool(false) [6]=> bool(true) [7]=> NULL [9]=> int(3) [10]=> string(2) "hi" [11]=> int(2) }

It's not so elegant and is probably not that fast, but seems to work.

It will keep only the last value in the array.

Working example: [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c7aa0d9d37b707d498630ef9e8e124c5cfe945d)

Answer (score 1):

i was bored :)

```
$a = ['test',1, true, null, false,null,'test',true];

function arrayUnique($a)
{
    $u=array();
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        if(!in_array($v,$u,TRUE)){
          $u[]=$v;  
        }

    }
        return $u;
}

var_dump(arrayUnique($a));
```

Output:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> int(1) [2]=> bool(true) [3]=> NULL [4]=> bool(false) }
```